# ObjectAnimator with array variable

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator

I'm building a custom view  contains three progress bars, therefore I have an array variable, like this one:

```
float[] progress = new float[3];
```

And I want to update specific progress entry using 'ObjectAnimator'; here are the relevant methods:

```
public void setProgress(int index, float progress) {
    this.progress[index] = (progress<=100) ? progress : 100;
    invalidate();
}

public void setProgressWithAnimation(int index, float progress, int duration) {
    PropertyValuesHolder indexValue = PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("progress", index);
    PropertyValuesHolder progressValue = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("progress", progress);

    ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(this, indexValue, progressValue);
    objectAnimator.setDuration(duration);
    objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    objectAnimator.start();
}
```

but I'm getting this warning: `Method setProgress() with type int not found on target class`

I also tried with setter contains an array (`setProgress (float[] progress)`) but still got an error:

> Method setProgress() with type float not found on target class

How can I use array variable in ObjectAnimator?

Comment: simply use `ObjectAnimator#ofInt(Object target, String propertyName, int... values)`

Comment: @pskink. thanks but I already try it and got: `Method setProgress() with type float not found on target class`, sorry I didn't wrote in the question that I tried it too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of attempts, it's looks like it's possible to do this using `ObjectAnimator`. I also found this in the [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#object-animator):

> The object property that you are animating must have a setter function
>   (in camel case) in the form of set(). Because the
>   ObjectAnimator automatically updates the property during animation, it
>   must be able to access the property with this setter method. For
>   example, if the property name is foo, you need to have a setFoo()
>   method. If this setter method does not exist, you have three options:
>
> - Add the setter method to the class if you have the rights to do so.
> - Use a wrapper class that you have rights to change and have that
>     wrapper receive the value with a valid setter method and forward it to
>     the original object.
> - Use ValueAnimator instead.

As Google advice, I tried with `ValueAnimator` and it's works fine:

```
public void setProgressWithAnimation(float progress, int duration, final int index) {
    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(progress);
    valueAnimator.setDuration(duration);
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            setProgress((Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue(), index);
        }
    });
    valueAnimator.start();
}
```